# Problems building HPL

Tags: centos, benchmarking, hpc, linpack

I'm trying to build Linpack on my laptop. I'm running CentOS 8, along with Open MPI and blas 3.8.0.

The makefile is running alright till startup and refresh, but getting an error at the build part.

**ERROR**

```
mpicc -o HPL_dlamch.o -c  -DHPL_CALL_CBLAS -I/home/aditya/hpl/include -I/home/aditya/hpl/include/Linux_PII_CBLAS  -I/home/aditya/anaconda3/include  ../HPL_dlamch.c
ar r /home/aditya/hpl/lib/Linux_PII_CBLAS/libhpl.a  HPL_dlacpy.o           HPL_dlatcpy.o          HPL_fprintf.o HPL_warn.o             HPL_abort.o            HPL_dlaprnt.o HPL_dlange.o HPL_dlamch.o
ar: /home/aditya/hpl/lib/Linux_PII_CBLAS/libhpl.a: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [Makefile:72: lib.grd] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/aditya/hpl/src/auxil/LINUX_PII_CBLAS'
make[1]: *** [Make.top:54: build_src] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/aditya/hpl'
make: *** [Makefile:72: build] Error 2
```

**Make.LINPACK_PII_CBLAS**

```
MPdir        = /home/aditya/anaconda3
MPinc        = -I$(MPdir)/include
MPlib        = $(MPdir)/lib/libmpi.so

MPdir        = /home/aditya/anaconda3
MPinc        = -I$(MPdir)/include
MPlib        = $(MPdir)/lib/libmpi.so

HPL_INCLUDES = -I$(INCdir) -I$(INCdir)/$(ARCH) $(LAinc) $(MPinc)
HPL_LIBS     = $(HPLlib) $(LAlib) $(MPlib)
```